# Flask IIS error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wfastcgi, httpplatformhandler

I have created a simple python code to test Flask and IIS as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():
        return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

    return app
```

I have configured my IIS but when I try to access my page, I have the following error:

[image]

If I try to see the markupsafe, it shows me that it is installed:
[image]

I do not know what I have to do so the Flask can find the module. They both are on the same directory.

Anyone could help me, please?

PS: I tried to execute using both wfastcgi and HttpProtocol but both give me the same error.